# can't pull docker images from nexus proxy

Tags: docker, proxy, nexus

The nexus is configured at 8444 for internal hosting and the 7001 for the external proxy. I am able to pull images from 8444. But can't pull anything from the internet. The nexus is pointing to https://registry-1.docker.io in the proxy settings. Any suggestions?

```
$ docker pull x.com:8444/hello-world
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from hello-world
c04b14da8d14: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:a18ed77532f6d6781500db650194e0f9396ba5f05f8b50d4046b294ae5f83aa4
Status: Downloaded newer image for x.com:8444/hello-world:latest

$ docker pull  x.com:7001/node
Using default tag: latest
Error response from daemon: unknown: unknown
```

(there is no error log showing in nexus for this pull)

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer myself. In the configuration, need to use

> "Use Docker Hub"

option in the Proxy->Docker index.
I used "Use proxy registry (specified above)" which doesn't work.